# I was learning Matplotlib and i came across `ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()`. My question is written below

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
for ax in plt.gcf().get_axes():
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_visible(True)
```

This was the for loop to write xtick and ytick in every plot. But I couldn't understand what is `ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()`. What does "+" sign indicate there? and what does `plt.gcf().getaxes()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ax.get_xticklabels()` and `ax.get_yticklabels()` both return list-like objects. The `+` operator just concats the two lists

`plt.gcf()` returns the current figure. `plt.gcf().getaxes()` returns the axes of the current figure.

More explaination [here](https://www.listendata.com/2019/06/matplotlib-tutorial-learn-plot-python.html)

[image]

Comment: so are we allowed to do concatenate in for loop too? Thanks for editing the question and for the answer. This figure explains it all.

Comment: It more likes `a = list1 + list2` and `for label in a: ...` than concatenate in for loop : )

Comment: I see. Thanks bro :)